# HTML5 Videos flickering

Tags: google-chrome

When watching html5 videos on youtube or any other websites like vimeo, streamcloud, etc, videos flicker from time to time (upperhalf is like 5px to the left from the down half). Am using Ubuntu 16.04 and using the integrated gpu from i7 4702mq (browser is Chrome). Does not happen in Firefox. Also tried to restore all flags to default, not helping :( (Notebook: MSI Ge40 with nvidia 760m & 4702mq i7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can try:

- go to `chrome://flags` and DISABLE `Smooth Scrolling`
- Make sure `Use hardware acceleration when available` is checked in
  Chrome's advanced settings

You could consider updating kernel as well. This worked for me with i7 integrated graphics platform to cure many annoying glitches and is an easy way of getting updated Intel drivers.

NB: `Smooth Scrolling` is normally set to `default` which works well for me with screen lines scrolling smoothly in chrome.

Comment: How do I update the kernel? (Have the latest ubuntu from ubuntu.com) Tried the rest and it actually fixed it, but damn this browser sucks my battery out...

Comment: Now that the original question has been solved I think two new questions should be posted: `How do I update Ubuntu 16.04 to Kernel 4.7.3?` (which also reduces battery drain as a side-effect) and `How do I reduce browser battery drain?` (which many others can answer better than me).

Comment: Why should I update if it is working now? About the battery drain, posted it, nobody could help...

Comment: Indeed I recommend not updating kernel unless there is a specific problem to be solved. For myself updating stopped Intel CPU Turbo Boost from constantly running and laptop running 10c to 20c hotter than it should. I also had suspend/resume issues but tried many things and the kernel update may not have been the sole solution. If you don't have the same problems as I did there are no reasons to update. Mostly users with new hardware are forced to get Kernel updates to fix glitches. In my case the laptop is from 2012 but still benefited. Kernel updates are frowned upon by some in this forum....